# Как сделать ссылку на файл /*.html на сервере apache2?

Tags: apache, php7

Файл index.php открывается и запускается на локальном сервере корректно,а сопутствующие файлы(например /kontakty.html) - не открываются,выдает ошибку :

> The requested URL /kontakty.html was not found on this server.

Проблема скорее всего не в исходном коде,писал его не я. Возможно, дело в конфигурации apache2. Буду рад вашим советам. 
[image]

Comment: Без показа конфигурации апача помощи можно ждать только от телепатов. Давайте показывайте, где у вас DocumentRoot и есть ли (`ls`) в этой папке искомый html-файл.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bxmMb
В самой директории public_html1 данных *.html файлов нет , но как я понял index.php должен делать ссылку на подпапки

Comment: На so принято информацию приводить в вопросе, а не на сторонних сервисах. Плюс, я не вижу `ls /var/www` - есть ли там файлы?

Comment: Да,есть директория самого сайта и директория html в которой находится директория с названием phpmyadmin,то есть ls выводит директории html и *название сайта*.ru .  Прошу прощения за ссылку,еще не освоился на этом сайте.

Comment: Главная страница (то есть index.php,что находится в директории sait.ru/public_html1) функционирует отлично,но при переходе по вкладкам,например при переходе на вкладку "Контакты" выдает данную ошибку.

Comment: Есть ли в каталоге /var/www/site.ru/public_html и файл kontakty.html или нет? Есть ли rewrite-правила?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том что не было конфигурационного файла .htaccess с конфигурацией joomla. После добавления проблема решилась.

```
    ##
# @package  Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license  GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations. It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file. If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's. If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```